# Error when trying to use ag-grid in ionic2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2, ag-grid

I am new to Ionic 2 and to AG-grid. I have been playing with an example ionic 2 template (sidemenu), and imported into Visual Studio 2015. All seems to run fine.

I want to find a data grid to use, and came across ag-grid. so wanted to explore this in Ionic 2 application.

Following the instructions [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/index.php), I've installed the node package, so I have the following in my package.json

```
"ag-grid": "^4.2.7",
"ag-grid-ng2": "^4.2.2",
```

I have imported into the test .ts file and included the directive ..

```
...
import {AgGridNg2} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main'
import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid/main'

@Component({
   directives: [AgGridNg2],
   templateUrl: 'build/pages/aggrid-page/aggrid-page.html'
})
export class AgGridPage {
   public data: Array<GridRow>;
   public columnDefs;
   public gridOptions: any;
   public showToolPanel;
   ...
```

Now, I am not sure what to do with the line than mention the SystemX..

```
System.config({
packages: {
    lib: {
...
```

so I have not done anything there.

I've also included the css files in index.html

```
<link href="../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css"    rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and I am getting 404 for these (not sure why, as the path seem correct).

The biggest error is the ag-grid tag creates an error.

So as per the example I have the following in my page html..

```
<ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" class="ag-fresh"    
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  [showToolPanel]="showToolPanel"
  [rowData]="rowData"

  // boolean values 'turned on'
  enableColResize
  enableSorting
  enableFilter

  // simple values, not bound
  rowHeight="22"
  rowSelection="multiple">  
</ag-grid-ng2>
```

However, when I run (using ionic serve), I get the following error..

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "ag-grid-ng2" ("


 [ERROR ->]</ag-grid-ng2>
 </ion-content>
 "): AgGridPage@31:2
```

So it's not liking the ag-grid-ng2 tag, so I have not set something up right.

Does anyone know if there are more step involved in integrating this ag-grid to Ionic? IS there something more that needs to include the ag-grid lib files into app.bundle.js?

Thank in advance for any help

Comment: I also included ag-grid-ng2 with an ionic 2 project as you did and get the following error: 

app.bundle.js:49643 Uncaught TypeError: core_1.NgModule is not a function(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:49643378../agComponentFactory @ app.bundle.js:49655s @ app.bundle.js:1(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:1380../lib/agAware @ app.bundle.js:49751s @ app.bundle.js:1(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:11../components/sidebar/sidebar @ app.bundle.js:15s @ app.bundle.js:1e @ app.bundle.js:1(anonymous function) @ app.bundle.js:1
Navigated to http://localhost:8100/?restart=719616

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the closing bracket `>`:

```
  rowHeight="22"
  rowSelection="multiple"> <=== here
</ag-grid-ng2>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, may have been a copy paste error when I was trying to cut our some of the detail. I've make sure that I did have this closing > (updated the code block above) and removed the comments and the error  is gone (no gird yet but this error is gone). Cheers!

Comment: I can confirm it was the comments that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the **stylesheets**: You either need to change your gulp task to include them in the build (stylesheets are not included by default) or as I did copy or symlink both css files to your app/themes directory, rename them as *.scss and import them into app.core.scss. They will then be included into your app css in build/css.

Example:

```
@import "./ag-grid";
@import "./theme-fresh";
```